# php warning if not root : cannot open shared object file

Tags: php, ubuntu

When i launch `php -v`, it works well but if i reun the same commend with a specifi user `sudo -u www-data php -v` i have a warning :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: 
usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so (libmql1.so: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so 
(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2021 19:41:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

When i look specificly to the oci8 extension, i can see the same problem, with "not found"' messages :

```
root@c1cd0fdb57bb:/var/www/html# ldd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2405d000)
    libclntsh.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 (0x00007f2d7c9a8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2d7c7e1000)
    libmql1.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libmql1.so (0x00007f2d7c56a000)
    libipc1.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libipc1.so (0x00007f2d7c137000)
    libnnz12.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libnnz12.so (0x00007f2d7b9ee000)
    libons.so => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libons.so (0x00007f2d7b7a0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2d7b799000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2d7b616000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2d7b5f5000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f2d7b5dc000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2d7b5d2000)
    libaio.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f2d7b5cd000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f2d7b5b1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2d8047e000)
    libclntshcore.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntshcore.so.12.1 (0x00007f2d7afe3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2d7afc9000)
root@c1cd0fdb57bb:/var/www/html# sudo -u www-data ldd /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/oci8.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda4be5000)
    libclntsh.so.12.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 (0x00007f7dff109000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7dfef42000)
    libmql1.so => not found
    libipc1.so => not found
    libnnz12.so => not found
    libons.so => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7dfef3b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7dfedb8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7dfed97000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f7dfed7e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7dfed74000)
    libaio.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f7dfed6f000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f7dfed53000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7e02bdf000)
    libclntshcore.so.12.1 => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7dfed39000)
```

i tried to do a `chown -R www-data:www-data` on differents folders but i have the same error.

What can i do ?

Environment : UBUNTU

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, i ran these commands :

```
echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
ldconfig
```